# Can not push current commit to remote origin

Tags: git, git-push

This is my git log.

[image]

When I try to push commit to remote

```
$ git push -u origin master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date
```

But last two commit is not push, how to fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried rebasing your local master with origin?

Comment: @KatariaA What would be the expected result of this? `master` and `origin/master` are pointing at the same commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log shows that your `master` and `origin/master` are actually at the same point, and your two new commits are not on any branch.

At this point you can proceed in different ways, for example get on your local `master` branch and cherry-pick both commits :

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick 4127d7c
git cherry-pick a52d454
```

Then your earlier push should have the effect you expected.

---

Another (maybe faster) way to proceed would be to set the ref on master directly :

```
git branch -f master a52d454
git push origin master
```

---

...and just to mention it, this *other* other variant :

```
git push +a52d454:master
git checkout master
git pull
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I am not on master branch, I do this:

```sh
# go to master branch
$ git checkout master

# merge last commit
$ git merge a52d4541a4c7

# push to remote
$ git push
```

that is fine.

Comment: Even simpler. I love it :-)